Conditionally declare a variable of a certain type
Here is what I want to achieve:
struct A { A(/* ... */) {} A(A const&) = delete; };
struct B { B(/* ... */) {} B(B const&) = delete; };

int main()
{
    static bool constexpr cond = false;

    [[maybe_unused]]
    A a(/* ... */);
    [[maybe_unused]]
    B b(/* ... */);

    std::conditional_t<cond, A, B> c = cond ? a : b;

    return 0;
}

This doesn't compile, since the "?" operator requires both types to be convertible to each other. What I (obviously) need is that c is a or b depending on wheter cond is true or false. How can I achieve that?

auto& c = std::get<cond ? 0 : 1>(std::tie(a, b)); Something like that.

Or auto c = [&]{ if constexpr (cond) return a; else return b; }();.

A side question: would it have any bad side effects if the ternary operator was relaxed to allow for non-convertible types on its both sides?

@krzysiek - It would break horribly when cond is not constexpr. And the operator is also the base for std::common_type, which has the condition "if such a type exists".

There's another problem with your code. Since you've deleted copy ctor for both A and B, std::conditional_t<cond, A, B> c =...  can't possibly work.

@user12002570 You are right. Should be replaced by a reference.

Something which technically works, but isn't very pretty:
auto& c = [&] -> auto& {
    if constexpr (cond) return a;
    else                return b;
}();

// rest of function ...

This relies on if constexpr being able to influence the deduced return type of this lambda expression.
Therefore, it also relies on cond being a constant expression.
However, it is pretty rare that you would have to do this.
Usually, you would write a function template which works with either A or B and then pass in the appropriate object.
// f could also be a separate function
auto f = [&](auto& c) {
    // rest of function ...
};

// this uses "if constexpr", but would work with a regular if statement too
if constexpr (cond) f(a);
else                f(b);


Side question: You did not specify an empty parameter list in your lambda. Is this valid? Shouldn't it be auto c = [&]() { ... }(); instead? Also: As remarked in the comments of the question, I need to return a reference. I ended up with auto& c = [&]() -> auto& { ... }();. Without the empty parameter list, this isn't working anymore.

@0xbadf00d it's valid since C++23. In C++20, you'd need the empty parentheses.
